# C++ key-value container with variable type values

Tags: c++, algorithm

What I need is a key-value container for keeping some well-known parameters of objects. All possible keys are known on compile time. Values are belong to differnt types: POD (integers, pointers) and non-POD (some small structures with contructors).

Current implementation uses very big structure and tons of code to initialize, fill and copy values. So I want to replace this structure with container. Container must provide:
1) quick access by key (constant time).
2) the possibility to iterate over all values to copy them.

I tried to think up some array based approach, but coldn't make it. I can make some hash table, but I don't know what to do with different value types.

Comment: You said `All possible keys are known on compile time`, then you must be knowing the *type* as well. Why is the *type* of key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look at [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/variant.html) for storing the values.  Then you can just use a `std::map<Key, boost::variant>` or `std::unordered_map<Key, boost::variant>` for your container.

Comment: Thanks. I did not known about Boost.Variant.

Answer (score 4):

sounds like `std::unordered_map` (or `boost::unordered_map`) is the right solution. Just use `boost::any` for the objects so they can be any type.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like the `std::map` is the right way to go.

While your keys are known at compile time, you may just populate the std::map structure with the data as part of the initialization.

For the value, you probably want to implement a wrapper objects which can hold int, pointers, and some of your simple-non-POD objects, and then make that your second (value) object in the std::hash table.

std::map, inplements `.find(key)` for fast lookup and `.begin()` and `.end()` for `::iterator`'s

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> All possible keys are known on compile time.

then you must be knowing the *type* as well.

**If** the *type* is integral type, then *array* or *pointer* of `boost::any` is the best choice.

```
//if the size is known at compile time!
boost::any objmap[size]; 

//if the size isn't known at compile time
boost::any *objmap = new boost::any[size];
```

Whatever you use (array or pointer), the *key* will be the index of `objmap` and `objmap[key]` will be the value associated with the *key*.

Comment: The value types are non-heterogeneous though.

Comment: @Mark B: In that case, he can use `boost::any` for value type. I edited my post as well.